# modal only working on first link

Tags: iframe, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page with multiple links to activate a modal, the issue is the first link works but none of the others allows the content to load in the modal.

```
<a href="URL" id="dialog-iframe" title="TITLE">link to Modal</a>

 $("#dialog-iframe").dialog2IFrame( {
              height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue - put it in a class

```
<a href="URL" class="dialog-iframe" title="TITLE">link to Modal</a>
```

$(".dialog-iframe").dialog2IFrame( {
              height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,

```
        });
```